# Dual Channel Mode(RAM)

Tags: windows, memory, dual-channel

My existing Build has **2 * 4GB** RAM [G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231314])

Processor : [i5-4690](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JST2QEW)

Motherboard : [ASRock H97M Pro4](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157512&cm_re=asrock_h97m_pro4-_-13-157-512-_-Product)

Currently my memory run's in `Dual Channel mode`. Am planning to upgrade my memory with 
 **2 * 8GB**. [G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 16GB (2 x 8GB)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231489&cm_re=G.SKILL_16GB_%282_x_8GB%29-_-20-231-489-_-Product)

Now my question is, After upgrading will system work in `Dual Channel mode`. Since memory is like **2 * 4GB** + **2 * 8GB**

Also is it advisable to upgrade the `RAM` with same manufacturer. Currently my **2 * 4GB** is from `G SKILL` is it advisable to buy **2 * 8GB** from Corsair.

Comment: Mixing different manufacturers is generally okay. My laptop shipped with Super Talent memory; adding G.SKILL memory did not cause any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will still have an equal amount of memory on each channel, so the motherboard should remain in dual channel mode. Just put the new memory in the open slots.

Matching RAM manufacturers doesn't make any difference. There's nothing special that all RAM from Corsair has in common. Just make sure all your RAM can run at the same voltage and remember that you'll be limited to the speed of the slowest RAM stick.

Comment: What do you mean by *you'll be limited to the speed of the slowest RAM stick.*

Comment: @VR46 Exactly that. If you have a stick of 1066MHz and a stick of 1333MHz, they'll both match to run at the speed of the slower one, in this case, 1066.

Comment: I get that now. All my modules are of 1600mhz

Comment: If all are 1600MHz then that is the speed at which they will run. On a MB that has 4 memory slots, make sure which two are a single channel as in which two are channel 1 and which two are channel 2 and put, in this case, 12GB on each channel.